# Scan for bluetooth devices - Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bluetooth

I would like to know how to scan for all available devices and display these devices in a combobox, suing flash air for android and the bluetooth ane?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know ActionScript 3 does not support bluetooth, you can however use Peer to Peer connection over wifi. A tutorial I found very helpful was http://indigo-entertainment.com/blogs/view/6/26. I hope this helps!